# Concatenate strings with dots equals

Tags: php, concatenation

I've got a problem with concatenation: I would like to add sku value between [ ], but not sure how to start with

```
$items .= $_item->getProduct()->getData('sku') . '] '. $_item->getProduct()->getName() . '  x '. $_item->getQty() . '  '
                . $checkout->getStoreCurrencyCode() . ' '
                . $_item->getProduct()->getFinalPrice($_item->getQty()) . "\n";
```

shoud I use something like this?
I would like to have: [SKU] Title x Quantity

```
$items .= '['. $_item->getProduct()->getData('sku') . '] '. $_item->getProduct()->getName() . '  x '. $_item->getQty() . '  '
```

Comment: You might consider adding a tag regarding the programming language so users can find your post easier.

Comment: Is it PHP code?

Comment: yes, it's PHP code

Comment: show your desired output as well in your question.

Comment: I would like to have [SKU] Title x Quantity

Comment: @SamProvides `$items .= ' [' . $_item->getProduct()->getData('sku') . '] ' . $_item->getProduct()->getName() . ' x ' . $_item->getQty();`

Comment: What happens if you try your `shoud I use something like this`?